# Which algorithm returns the shortest sequence to exchange information between knots of a graph?

Tags: algorithm

Is there a Tool or known algorithmic method, which could compute the shortest sequence to transmit an information between the knots of a graph - e.g. graph **threeC** ?

[image: graphs]

Example: **threeC**

Time 0: A=a; B=b; C=c; D=d

Time 1: A=abcd; B=b; C=c; D=d

Time 2: A=abcd; B=bacd; C=cabd; D=dabc

---

I've looked into petri-nets, it would have to be a coloured net with directed and multiple edges - I guess. However I am quite uncertain, if I am on the right track.

It would have to work for connected unlabelled Graphs up to 5 knots (there are 21 of those). I would like to know - better proof - the shortest way of distributing *abcd* amongst all 5 knots (for all of those 21 graphs).

So, is there an algorithm or field of research that fits to this problem?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you can use Mathlab: http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/graphallshortestpaths.html

Comment: not quite - made an edit - one of those graphs would be fully connected - now how can you proove that a specific sequence of information exchange is the shortest sequence possible? You may walk edges multiple times; you may use edges synchronously. At the end every knot has to have a token from every other knot

Comment: the problem is, that I am not looking for just a path - but a sequence like stated in my example above; nevertheless your link is informative and useful to me - thanks

Comment: The sequence will be at least as long, as the longest path between any two nodes. If you know all the shortest paths, you can easily generate a sequence from them. For example in you threeC: the shortest path between B and D is B-A-D. So in the first step there will be a B->A and a D->A transaction (travel both directions). In the second step there will be an A->D and an A->b transaction. All such path will contribute something to the sequence. (Time 0->Time1 will be the first edge of all the shortest path, Time 1->Time 2 will be the second, etc.).

Comment: The mathlab script will not work for you because it only returns the length of the path. This [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#All-pairs_shortest_paths) page will get you on the right track.

Comment: The Algorithm of Floyd and Warshall looks promising I'll look more into that, thanks!

Comment: This is basically BFS from every node?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the question is actually to find the shortest path to the vertex that is father from starting vertex. That would be exactly what Dijkstra would do very well. You basically only assign a start node for Dijkstra and let it run until it has visited all nodes.
Dijkstra would leave behind information required for output.

If output is single value telling the maximum shortest path you can simple keep track of distance and print the highest distance when algorithm terminates. If requirement is to output also paths then Dijkstra would need to store information which edges it used to travel from a vertices that resulted to the shortest path in other end of vertex (there could be multiple equal entrances to a vertex requiring all sources to have their edges marked as used for route if all paths are required for output.)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm